# How can I change the Text content using DOM in node js

Tags: node.js, express

What I want to do is that
I want to change the

tag to incorrect password when a wrong password is entered
but am getting error
**ReferenceError: document is not defined**
this is my HTML file

```html
<form action="/check" method="POST">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <p></p>
</form>
```

and here is my javascript file content

```js
import express from "express";
import {dirname} from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const pass = "ILoveProgramming";
var enter = "";
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

function checker(req, res, next){
    enter = req.body.password;
    console.log(enter);
    next();
}

app.use(checker);

app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname +"/public/index.html");
});

app.post("/check",(req,res)=>{
    if(pass === enter){
        res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/secret.html");
    }
    else{
        document.querySelector("p").textContent("The paswrd is wrong");
        console.log("The password is incorrect");
    }
    // console.log(enter);
});

app.use(bodyParser);

app.listen(port, () =>{
   console.log(`server is live at ${port}`);
});
```

I am new to all this so take me as someone without any experience

Comment: r u using templating engine or you have a separate client

Comment: I am not using any templating engine, just only html and js (nodejs with express)

Answer (score 3):

`document` object is part of the browser's DOM API, it is not available on the server side. on the browser console, it is property of `window` object. `window.document`.

you're trying to manipulate the DOM on the server, which is not possible. You should handle the DOM manipulation on the client side after the browser has received and rendered the HTML page. For this, you should have a `script` tag inside HTML file.

```
<script>
// inside here you add your logic to access document
</script>
```

`script` tag will get executed on the browser and you can access to `document` object inside this tag

Comment: Thanks mate, Well I leant EJS and used it to change the text to what ever I want,
Thanks again for ur input